# Python: can a decorator determine if a function is being defined inside a class?

Tags: python, inspect

I'm writing a decorator, and for various annoying reasons[0] it would be expedient to check if the function it is wrapping is being defined stand-alone or as part of a class (and further which classes that new class is subclassing).

For example:

```
def my_decorator(f):
    defined_in_class = ??
    print "%r: %s" %(f, defined_in_class)

@my_decorator
def foo(): pass

class Bar(object):
    @my_decorator
    def bar(self): pass
```

Should print:

```
<function foo …>: False
<function bar …>: True
```

Also, please note:

- At the point decorators are applied the function will still be a function, not an unbound method, so testing for instance/unbound method  (using `typeof` or `inspect`) will not work.
- Please only offer suggestions that solve *this* problem — I'm aware that there are many similar ways to accomplish this end (ex, using a class decorator), but I would like them to happen at *decoration* time, not later.

[0]: specifically, I'm writing a decorator that will make it easy to do parameterized testing with `nose`. However, `nose` will *not* run test generators on subclasses of `unittest.TestCase`, so I would like my decorator to be able to determine if it's being used inside a subclass of `TestCase` and fail with an appropriate error. The obvious solution - using `isinstance(self, TestCase)` before calling the wrapped function doesn't work, because the wrapped function *needs* to be a generator, which doesn't get executed *at all*.

Comment: For the curious, here is the result: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/532430/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at the output of `inspect.stack()` when you wrap a method. When your decorator's execution is underway, the current stack frame is the function call to your decorator; the next stack frame down is the `@` wrapping action that is being applied to the new method; and the third frame will be the class definition itself, which merits a separate stack frame because the class definition is its own namespace (that is wrapped up to create a class when it is done executing).

I suggest, therefore:

```
defined_in_class = (len(frames) > 2 and
                    frames[2][4][0].strip().startswith('class '))
```

If all of those crazy indexes look unmaintainable, then you can be more explicit by taking the frame apart piece by piece, like this:

```
import inspect
frames = inspect.stack()
defined_in_class = False
if len(frames) > 2:
    maybe_class_frame = frames[2]
    statement_list = maybe_class_frame[4]
    first_statment = statement_list[0]
    if first_statment.strip().startswith('class '):
        defined_in_class = True
```

Note that I do *not* see any way to ask Python about the class name or inheritance hierarchy at the moment your wrapper runs; that point is "too early" in the processing steps, since the class creation is not yet finished. Either parse the line that begins with `class` yourself and then look in that frame's globals to find the superclass, or else poke around the `frames[1]` code object to see what you can learn — it appears that the class name winds up being `frames[1][0].f_code.co_name` in the above code, but I cannot find any way to learn what superclasses will be attached when the class creation finishes up.

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the party here, but this has proven to be a reliable means of determining if a decorator is being used on a function defined in a class:

```
frames = inspect.stack()

className = None
for frame in frames[1:]:
    if frame[3] == "<module>":
        # At module level, go no further
        break
    elif '__module__' in frame[0].f_code.co_names:
        className = frame[0].f_code.co_name
        break
```

The advantage of this method over the accepted answer is that it works with e.g. py2exe.

Comment: This may very well succeed on frozen apps (e.g., PyInstaller, py2exe), but **this certainly fails on unfrozen apps that nest classes** – a more common use case. `'__module__'` will *not* be in the `frame[0].f_code.co_names` tuple for nested classes, especially nested classes themselves localized to nested closures. Decorator authors just can't get a break here.

Answer (score 1):

Some hacky solution that I've got:

```
import inspect

def my_decorator(f):
    args = inspect.getargspec(f).args
    defined_in_class = bool(args and args[0] == 'self')
    print "%r: %s" %(f, defined_in_class)
```

But it relays on the presence of `self` argument in function.

Comment: **This is guaranteed to fail with both false positives and negatives.** `self` is just an ad-hoc community standard. Nothing enforces `self`, so nothing should expect there to exist a one-to-one relation between unbound methods and callables whose first arguments are coincidentally named `self`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the package `wrapt` to check for
 - instance/class methods
 - classes
 - freestanding functions/static methods:

See the project page of `wrapt`: https://pypi.org/project/wrapt/

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the decorator itself is being called at the module level or nested within something else.

```
defined_in_class = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_code.co_name != "<module>"
```

Comment: Hrm… But this wouldn't work for classes nested within something, would it? (ex, `def mk_class(): class MyClass: … ; return MyClass`)

Comment: What the function does or returns doesn't affect the value of `inspect.currentframe().f_back`; the only thing that matters is where `my_decorator` is called, and that's always going to be the same level at which the thing it wraps around is defined.

Comment: I might have misunderstood your comment; any decorated functions inside other functions won't run the decorator until the enclosing function is called, but the scope of the wrapped function will be computed correctly. You can use this inside the decorator to see a list of the enclosing scopes at the point when the decorator is run: `[x[0].f_code.co_name for x in inspect.stack()[1:]]`.

Comment: **This is guaranteed to fail with false positives,** notably for nested closures (i.e., functions declared within other functions declared within other functions). Nested closures are decoratable, but the `f_code.co_name` attribute of their parent closures is guaranteed to be a valid Python identifier and thus *not* `<module>`.

Answer (score -3):

I think the functions in the `inspect` module will do what you want, particularly [isfunction](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.isfunction) and [ismethod](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.ismethod):

```
>>> import inspect
>>> def foo(): pass
... 
>>> inspect.isfunction(foo)
True
>>> inspect.ismethod(foo)
False
>>> class C(object):
...     def foo(self):
...             pass
... 
>>> inspect.isfunction(C.foo)
False
>>> inspect.ismethod(C.foo)
True
>>> inspect.isfunction(C().foo)
False
>>> inspect.ismethod(C().foo)
True
```

You can then follow the [Types and Members table](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#types-and-members) to access the function inside the bound or unbound method:

```
>>> C.foo.im_func
<function foo at 0x1062dfaa0>
>>> inspect.isfunction(C.foo.im_func)
True
>>> inspect.ismethod(C.foo.im_func)
False
```

Comment: I expect that `inspect` will be involved, but not the way you've described. See my first note (that at the time decorators are applied the function is just an instance of `function`, not `unboundmethod` or `boundmethod`).

Comment: He didn't state it explicitly, but his point was this does not work at class definition time.

Comment: Yes, you're right — I've updated my question to be more explicit. I appreciate the thorough answer, it just doesn't address my question.