# How to use decorator in observer pattern for Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators

The observer pattern in the very simplified code below works well. I would like to have have a decorator `@on_event` that does the registration in the Observable singleton.

In class O2 below this does not work. The problem is of course that the decorator on_event get's called prior to the instance is created, and the registration will be to the unbound method `event`. In some way I have to delay the registration until the O2 object is initialized. Maybe needless to say but all I want to add in O2 is the decorator as in the code below.

But for sure there must be a solution to this? I have googled around but cannot find anything, and have tried several approaches.

```
class Observable(object):
    _instance = None

    @classmethod
    def instance(cls):
        if not cls._instance:
            cls._instance = Observable()
        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self):
        self.obs = []

    def event(self, data):
        for fn in self.obs:
            fn(data)

def on_event(f):
    def wrapper(*args):
        return f(*args)
    Observable.instance().obs.append(f)
    return wrapper

class O(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        Observable.instance().obs.append(self.event)

    def event(self, data):
        print self.name + " Event: " + data

class O2(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @on_event
    def eventx(self, data):
        print self.name + " Event: " + data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    o1 = O("o1")
    Observable.instance().event("E1")

    o2 = O2("o2")
    Observable.instance().event("E2")
```

Comment: So what *instance* should the method be called on then, when the event fires? That is the issue here; you can only register bound methods if there is an instance to bind the method *to*. What are you trying to register here? The method of just one `O2` instance, all instances of `O2`, something else?

Comment: @MartijnPieters in the example it should be called on the o2 instance - all instances of O2. (Exactly as O works)

Comment: You cannot do that with a decorator alone; you'd need to set a metaclass on `O2` as well to hook into instance creation, then register the bound method every time you create an instance.

Comment: Although theoretically the decorator could also insert a `__new__` or `__init__` method in to the same class namespace that then does hooking; but this gets ugly fast, and is not recommended.

Comment: (see [How does the function that is called inside the class declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13330660) for how ugly that can get; that specific trick won't even work in Python 3).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I would like to avoid that kind of solution. I hope someone has solved this. But I am starting to give up.

Comment: You can use a metaclass, plus a decorator for the function; that requires that the user of your observer pattern library has to specify the metaclass as well as decorate the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot register bound methods until you have an instance for the method to be bound *to*. A function decorator alone does not have the context to detect when an instance has been created.

You could use a metaclass / decorator combined approach instead:

```
class ObservingMeta(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):
         instance = super(ObservingMeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kw)
         for attr in vars(cls).values():
             if hasattr(attr, '__observer__'):
                 # register bound method
                 bound = attr.__get__(instance, cls)
                 Observable.instance().obs.append(bound)
         return instance
```

This registers all methods *directly* defined on `cls` that are marked as observers; the marking is done with a decorator:

```
def on_event_method(f):
    f.__observer__ = True
    return f
```

This is then used as:

```
class O2(object):
    __metaclass__ = ObservingMeta

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    @on_event_method
    def eventx(self, data):
        print self.name + " Event: " + data
```

Do note that storing the methods in your `Observable` singleton keeps the instances alive; if you create instances of `O2` the bound `eventx` methods reference the instance, and by keeping references to the methods that means the instances are never garbage collected if all other references to them are deleted.

See [using python WeakSet to enable a callback functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826700/using-python-weakset-to-enable-a-callback-functionality) for how you could use weak references instead to only keep tabs on methods until the underlying instance has been deleted, without keeping the instances alive indefinitely.

Comment: This solution solves the problem stated in the question, however I really wanted a solution where the same decorator could be used on module level aswell. Reason beeing that the problem was that the decorator did not work in a class.

Comment: Yes, but that'd require detecting you are in a class definition and adjusting how you register the function. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793233/python-can-a-decorator-determine-if-a-function-is-being-defined-inside-a-class. Again, rather ugly, and *any* function can be turned into a method, really.